# DisplacementMapFilter not showing up in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I have a problem with creating and applying displacement maps filters on a container Sprite. The setup is like this

```
public class ExplosionManager
{
    [Embed...] // this is an image I tested, basically a spherical displacement
    private var explodeDisplaceAsset:Class;
    private var explodeDisplace:Bitmap;
    private var displacementFilters:Array = new Array();
    private var displacementMaps:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>();
    private var unusedFilters:Vector.<DisplacementMapFilter> = new Vector.<DisplacementMapFilter>();
    private var unusedMaps:Vector.<BirmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>();

    public function ExplosionManager(container:Sprite)
    {
         explodeDisplace = new explodeDisplaceAsset();
         container.filters = displacementFilters;
    }
    public function ExplodeAt(pos:Point, force:int) : void
    {
         var newDisplaceMap:BitmapData;
         var newDisplaceFilter:DisplacementMapFilter;
         if(unusedFilters.length == 0)
         {
             newDisplaceMap = new BitmapData(64,64,true, 0x808080);
             newDisplaceMap.draw(explodeDisplace);
             newDisplaceFilter = new DispalcementFilter(newDisplaceMap, pos, BitmapDataChannel.RED, BitmapDataChannel.GREEN, force, force);
         }
         else
         {
              newDisplaceMap = unusedMaps.pop();
              newDisplaceFilter = unusedFilters.pop();
              newDisplaceFilter.componentX = force;
              newDisplaceFilter.componentY = force;
              newDisplaceFilter.mapPoint = pos;
              newDisplaceFilter.mapBitmap = newDisplaceMap;
         }
         displacementMaps.push(newDisplaceMap);
         displacementFilters.push(newDisplaceFilter);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make an adaptive object pool that reuses and creates filters as needed, my initial thought was that if I have about 2-3 explosions tops it'd be more efficient to have 2-3 filters that only get applied to a part of the scene rather than have one filter with a single big bitmap that gets updated every frame.
The problem is that I can't see any displacement no matter what combination of parameters I try, is there something I'm doing wrong ?

PS: I'm sorry if the code has some typos, I'm not at my development machine right now, so I had to rewrite it, but from the algorithms' point of view that's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Were do you apply the filter in the code? Are you adding the Bitmap object to display list anywhere?

Comment: I thought that this line would suffice container.filters = displacementFilters;

Comment: I am adding the filter in the constructor of the explosion manager, I wasn't aware it was necessary to add the bitmap to the display list, the online tutorials I followed only added it for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're assigning the array `displacementFilters` to the [`filters`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#filters) property within the constructor (at setup of the `ExplosionManager`). It then looks like you're adding and modifying filters within that array at a later date.

Unfortunately, changes made to the filters stored within the array you used as a source last time will not be applied to the object. This is because when you assign an array to `filters`, a copy of that array is actually created and used. From the documentation:

> To modify an existing filter object, you must use the technique of
>   modifying a copy of the filters array:
>
> 1. Assign the value of the filters array to a temporary array, such as
>      one named myFilters.
> 2. Modify the property by using the temporary array,
>      myFilters. For example, to set the quality property of the first
>      filter in the array, you could use the following code:
>      myFilters[0].quality = 1;
> 3. Assign the value of the temporary array to
>      the filters array.

You will need to assign the updated `displacementFilters` array to `filters` whenever there are changes made.

Comment: That was it, the filter array was empty when ti was initialized, thanks a lot.